# maintaining 24/7 discord bot uptime on compute engine

Tags: ubuntu, discord.py, google-compute-engine

I created an instance on GCP compute engine (ubuntu) and downloaded python using SSH. After that I git cloned for my discord bot by script. I'm able to run python3 bot.py via the SSH and run my bot. However, whenever I close the SSH or close my laptop, the bot disconnects. How can I keep it so compute engine and my discord bot have 100% uptime?

Comment: A workaround is to use screen, tmux, or similar programs. If you want 100% uptime, then you will need to create a service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm quite new to all of this, can you elaborate on these programs?

Comment: amazing. i'm utilizing tmux and i think it works. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**There are many ways to have your script running 24/7 on Linux.**

For the purpose of this answer I will assume that you're running Debian 10 (default OS for a new VM).

1. **[Screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)** - in my opinion it's the most simple way to keep running your script after you disconnected. If you're running Debian you can install it with `sudo apt install screen`. Then you type `screen` and you're taken to your virtual screen where you run everything just as you would in a regular shell. After you started you script you can "detach" from it by pressing <kbd>`ctrl + a d`</kbd>. Then you can disconnect your SSH session and reconnect when you want (after few hours, days etc). Then you type `screen -r` and you just attached to your screen where your script is running. You can have multiple "screens" on your VM running at the same time too.
2. **[Tmux](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/tmux-tutorial-install-commands)** - [mentioned by John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69521175/maintaining-24-7-discord-bot-uptime-on-compute-engine#comment122881142_69521175) - has very similar functionality so I won't get into details.
3. **Create a service** - it's a "proper" way to run something continously - if for some reason your script will crash it can be automatically restarted (opposite to previous solutions). You can find a very good [tutorial on how to create your own service](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/) here. Another good example on how to create a service in Linux is [here](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6).